# use a list comprehension to double number until it reaches x

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, list-comprehension

I've produced the code below which works. However I would like to find a more Pythonic way using a list comprehension or Lambda to write the code.

```
n = 84

trillion = [n * 2, n *= 2 while n <= 1000000000000]
```

OR

```
lambda n: n*=2 while n <= 1000000000000

number = 84
while number <= 1000000000000:  
    print (number * 2) 
    number *= 2


168
336
772
```

Comment: Short-circuiting comprehensions were rejected in [PEP 3142](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3142/).  The while loop is fine here.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you just want to find the number, you don't need to loop at all, and certainly not a list comprehension, which would return a list. If you're just using the number as an example, please edit your question to clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want a list comprehension when there are no lists involved. However, you can simply use logarithms to compute the final result. I also suggest you use `10 ** 12` or `1_000_000_000_000` instead of `1000000000000` to make it a little bit more readable:

```
import math

number = 84

number *= 2 ** int(math.log2(10 ** 12 / number))

print(number)
```

---

```
721554505728
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the number to double each time until it reaches a trillion. So 168, 336, 772 etc

Comment: @Shegs84 The final result is the same. Do you need to store the intermediate results?